# TextInputEditText não pode ser convertido

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

Esse aqui é minha classe activity.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout;

public class FormularioCadastroActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextInputLayout textInputNomeCompleto;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_formulario_cadastro);
        textInputNomeCompleto = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.formulario_cadastro_campo_nome_completo);
        EditText campoNomeCompleto = textInputNomeCompleto.getEditText();
        String nomeCompleto = campoNomeCompleto.getText().toString();
        if(nomeCompleto.isEmpty()){
            campoNomeCompleto.setError("Campo Obrigatório");
        }
    }
}
```

O código XML correspondente a esse:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
    android:id="@+id/formulario_cadastro_campo_nome_completo"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:hint="Nome Completo"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"/>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/formulario_cadastro_campo_nome_completo">

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Essa é a mensagem de erro que receno:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText cannot be cast to com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
```

Também estou fornecendo o arquivo gradle para o caso de haver algo errado com a versão do **material**.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.qintess.cadastroqintess.ui.cadastroqintess"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'

}
```

Então, alguém tem idéia de como corrigir essa exceção?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No XML, o seu elemento com id `formulario_cadastro_campo_nome_completo` é um elemento `TextInputEditText`.

No código Java, você está tentando colocá-lo em uma variável do tipo `TextInputLayout`, por isso o erro é sobre não poder converter os tipos.

Para arrumar, basta deixar os dois (XML e Java) com o mesmo tipo de acordo com a sua necessidade.

Exemplo:

**Java**

```
private TextInputLayout textInputLayoutNomeCompleto;
private TextInputEditText textInputEditNomeCompleto;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    textInputLayoutNomeCompleto = findViewById(R.id.textInputLayout);
    textInputEditNomeCompleto = findViewById(R.id.formulario_cadastro_campo_nome_completo);
}
```

Não é necessário deixar o *casting* explícito no `findViewById`, pois quando você armazena numa variável a `View` retornada já é convertida para o tipo da variável.

Também é possível armazenar esse elemento em uma variável do tipo `EditText` pois o [`TextInputEditText`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputEditText) herda `EditText`. Caso você queira usar algum método mais específico do componente do Material, aí sim você precisa utilizar a classe mais específica :)